# How to make my code independent of "RTOS"?

Tags: c, freertos, rtos, lwip, cmsis

I want to to write a module that need some RTOS APIs like Mbox and Task creation API !

I'm trying to have structured code and to do that I'm looking at some libraries like "lwip" . In "lwip" there is a file named Sys-arch.c which in my knowledge is an abstraction layer to RTOS APIs ! but in my port it included cmsis_os.h and used that APIs . Why did they do that instead of using cmsis_os directly?

Should I have a new OS layer in order to have portable code or CMSIS_OS is enough ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is very opinion based.

In my experience it is always a good idea to use function/defines around your OS accesses. If you use CMSIS_OS or your own layer doesn't make a big difference beside you have more work if you use your own and especially porting and testing becomes very cumbersome with more than one OS.

The CMSIS_OS binds you to the Cortex-M systems but since they implement what you would implement in your layer as well and in quite usual way, it is rather simple to port from CMSIS_OS to your own layer later. It is not that simple if you use direct calls to a specific OS in your code directly but it is also possible if you only rely on standard features (take a look at CMSIS_OS what are common features of RTOS are) and don't use special features of your OS.

Answer (score 1):

> Why did they do that instead of using cmsis_os directly?

Because:

- The idea is to abstract the API from *any* RTOS.  If your target did not use CMSIS RTOS, you'd have to write a porting layer in any case.
- the CMSIS RTOS API is ARM Cortex-M specific and lwip is not.

> Should I have a new OS layer in order to have portable code or CMSIS_OS is enough ?

CMSIS is only enough if you will only ever target ARM Cortex-M, and there is a CMSIS layer for any RTOS you might be required to use.  CMSIS is a portability abstraction, but not perhaps a *usability* abstraction.  You might choose to implement a simpler abstraction of your own over CMSIS that can also be ported to other targets.

Answer (score 0):

lwIP is nicely structured so that as long as your RTOS API supports its semantic requirements, then all you have to do is to adapt sys_arch.c to your OS API and you are done. By making sys_arch.c using the CMSIS_OS API abstraction, that would mean that you can use any CMSIS OS API compliant OS without changing that port of sys_arch.c. It's an extra layer of indirection that only you can decide whether it is worth it or not. If you do not plan to use different RTOS underneath, then there is no reason not to have a sys_arch.c that is specific to a single RTOS.

Anyway, lwIP RTOS requirements are fairly modest. Just about a dozen functions, but really only involve mailbox and semaphores with certain characteristics.